# How to convert an array of single digit integers into 2 digits or more

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have an array of single digit integers

```
[1,0,2,3,6,7,9,8]
```

How would I go about converting them into an array of say, 2 digit integers?

Like so:

```
[10, 23, 67, 98]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal for loop and increment `i` by `2` & multiply by 10

```js
let array = [1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8]

let finalArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
  finalArray.push(array[i]*10 + (array[i + 1]))
}
console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: I just started learning javascript this week so this was the easiest to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and take the n<sup>th</sup> value as index.

This approach works for each count of grouping digits.

```js
const
    group = (array, digits) => array.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        var j = Math.floor(i / digits);
        r[j] = (r[j] || 0) * 10 + v;
        return r;
    }, [])

console.log(group([1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8], 2));
console.log(group([1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8, 9], 3));
console.log(group([1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 8], 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from()` to create a new array with the length of the original array.length / the chunks size (2 in your case). Extract each chunk with `Array.slice()`, join, and convert back to a number:

```js
const chunkAndJoin = (chunkSize, arr) => 
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / chunkSize) }, (_, i) => 
    Number(arr.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize).join(''))
  )

const arr = [1,0,2,3,6,7,9,8]

const result = chunkAndJoin(2, arr)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and concat numbers as strings by using the iteration index:

```
const initial = [1,0,2,3,6,7,9,8];
const nextArr = initial.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
  if (index % 2 !== 0) return acc;
  acc.push(Number(String(value) + String(initial[index + 1])));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(nextArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), by checking if the last item in the accumulated array is less than 10 (then item should be appended), otherwise, you can add it to the array.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [1,0,2,3,6,7,9,8];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
  let last = acc.length-1;
  if(acc[last] < 10) {
    acc[last] = acc[last]*10 + n;
  } else {
    acc.push(n);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know javascript :D , but something like this.

```
var a = [1,0,2,3,6,7,9,8];
var b = [];
var length = a.length%2 == 0 ? a.length : a.length -1;
for(var i = 0,j=0; i < length; i++,j++){
    b[j] = a[i] + "" + a[++i];
}
```

P.S., if your arrays length % 2 != 0, then this code will just skip the last one element))